# UIAlertController crashes when running under XCode 6.1 debugger

Tags: xcode6.1, ios8.1, uialertcontroller

My iPad app (XCode 6.1.1, iOS 8.1.1, ARC, Storyboards) issues this code when verifying the user wants to delete a record:

```
//  create an action sheet
UIAlertController *view=   [UIAlertController
                             alertControllerWithTitle:@"Warning!"
                             message:NSLocalizedString(@"Are you sure you want to delete this appointment?",nil)
                             preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

UIAlertAction* yes = [UIAlertAction
                      actionWithTitle:@"Yes"
                      style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                      handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                      {
                          [self deleteSingleAppointment];
                          [view dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                      }];
UIAlertAction* no = [UIAlertAction
                     actionWithTitle:@"No"
                     style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                     {
                         //Do some thing here
                         [view dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                     }];

[view addAction:yes];
[view addAction:no];

view.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
view.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2.0, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2.0, 1.0, 1.0);
[self presentViewController: view animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This code runs just fine when I run it outside the debugger on the device; this is the error shown, the stack trace follows:

[image]

**UPDATED**  Here is the "stack trace" from 'bt':

> (lldb) bt
>   * thread #1: tid = 0x14e4ec, 0x0000000111437dd2 CoreFoundation`CFArrayGetValueAtIndex + 130, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
>       frame #0: 0x0000000111437dd2 CoreFoundation`CFArrayGetValueAtIndex + 130
>       frame #1: 0x00000001137461af CoreText`TCharStream::CopyBreakIterator(__CFString const*) + 251
>       frame #2: 0x0000000113745f7e CoreText`TCharStream::FindLineBreak(CFRange, bool, __CFString const*) const + 274
>       frame #3: 0x00000001136cde9c CoreText`TTypesetter::SuggestLineBreak(TLine const&, long, double, double) + 290
>       frame #4: 0x00000001136cdb52 CoreText`CTLineSuggestLineBreakWithOffset + 20
>       frame #5: 0x000000011a6158f3 UIFoundation`__NSStringDrawingEngine + 19550
>       frame #6: 0x000000011a610c6f UIFoundation`-[NSString(NSExtendedStringDrawing) boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:] + 198
>       frame #7: 0x000000010faa0305 UIKit`-[UILabel _textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:includingShadow:] + 1025
>       frame #8: 0x000000010fa9fda0 UIKit`-[UILabel textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:] + 76
>       frame #9: 0x000000010faa3852 UIKit`-[UILabel _intrinsicSizeWithinSize:] + 170
>       frame #10: 0x000000010faa3932 UIKit`-[UILabel intrinsicContentSize] + 76
>       frame #11: 0x000000010ff59ea4 UIKit`-[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _generateContentSizeConstraints] + 33
>       frame #12: 0x000000010ff59c64 UIKit`-[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _updateContentSizeConstraints] + 422
>       frame #13: 0x000000010ff610d6 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraints] + 163
>       frame #14: 0x000000010faa379d UIKit`-[UILabel updateConstraints] + 272
>       frame #15: 0x000000010ff606fa UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 248
>       frame #16: 0x000000010ff608f2 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 124
>       frame #17: 0x0000000111455194 CoreFoundation`CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
>       frame #18: 0x000000010ff6069b UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 153
>       frame #19: 0x000000010ff608f2 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 124
>       frame #20: 0x0000000111455194 CoreFoundation`CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
>       frame #21: 0x000000010ff6069b UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 153
>       frame #22: 0x000000010ff608f2 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 124
>       frame #23: 0x0000000111455194 CoreFoundation`CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
>       frame #24: 0x000000010ff6069b UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 153
>       frame #25: 0x000000010ff608f2 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 124
>       frame #26: 0x0000000111455194 CoreFoundation`CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
>       frame #27: 0x000000010ff6069b UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 153
>       frame #28: 0x000000010ff608f2 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 124
>       frame #29: 0x0000000111455194 CoreFoundation`CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
>       frame #30: 0x000000010ff6069b UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 153
>       frame #31: 0x000000010ff608f2 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 124
>       frame #32: 0x0000000111455194 CoreFoundation`CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
>       frame #33: 0x000000010ff6069b UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 153
>       frame #34: 0x000000010ff608f2 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 124
>       frame #35: 0x0000000111455194 CoreFoundation`CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
>       frame #36: 0x000000010ff6069b UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 153
>       frame #37: 0x000000010ff608f2 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 124
>       frame #38: 0x0000000111455194 CoreFoundation`CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
>       frame #39: 0x000000010ff6069b UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 153
>       frame #40: 0x000000010ff608f2 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 124
>       frame #41: 0x0000000111455194 CoreFoundation`CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
>       frame #42: 0x000000010ff6069b UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 153
>       frame #43: 0x000000010ff608f2 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 124
>       frame #44: 0x0000000111455194 CoreFoundation`CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
>       frame #45: 0x000000010ff6069b UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 153
>       frame #46: 0x000000010ff608f2 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 124
>       frame #47: 0x000000010edcbd6e Foundation`-[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 155
>       frame #48: 0x000000010ff60bd4 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraintsIfNeeded] + 565
>       frame #49: 0x000000010ff541e0 UIKit`-[UIWindow(UIConstraintBasedLayout) updateConstraintsIfNeeded] + 91
>       frame #50: 0x000000010ff6119e UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsAtEngineLevelIfNeeded] + 159
>       frame #51: 0x000000010f947b2d UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) _updateConstraintsAsNecessaryAndApplyLayoutFromEngine] + 114
>       frame #52: 0x000000010f953973 UIKit`-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 521
>       frame #53: 0x000000010f626de8 QuartzCore`-[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 150
>       frame #54: 0x000000010f61ba0e QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 380
>       frame #55: 0x000000010f61b87e QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 24
>       frame #56: 0x000000010f58963e QuartzCore`CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 242
>       frame #57: 0x000000010f58a74a QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::commit() + 390
>       frame #58: 0x000000010f58adb5 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 89
>       frame #59: 0x0000000111481dc7 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
>       frame #60: 0x0000000111481d20 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
>       frame #61: 0x0000000111477b53 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1123
>       frame #62: 0x0000000111477486 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
>       frame #63: 0x00000001122de9f0 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 161
>       frame #64: 0x000000010f8da420 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1282
>     * frame #65: 0x000000010ddba9a3 SalonBook`main(argc=3, argv=0x00007fff51e46488) + 115 at main.m:15
>       frame #66: 0x000000011100d145 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
>   (lldb)

I have restarted the Mac, but it still happens.  Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: You say "no stack trace" but if it stops at the (lldb) prompt in the debug console, what does it show if you type 'bt' there?

Comment: If you crash while in Xcode with the debugger active, there's a debug console in the lower view and to the right.  It should be paused and prompting for input.

Comment: @PhillipMills  Fantastic (bt that is), but it really doesn't show me anything useful, unless you can see something.... thanks so much for telling me about 'bt'... btw, this used to work, but stopped today!

Comment: Other than something connected to applying layout constraints to a label, I don't see anything useful either.  Sorry.